# How to create Undo/Redo operations in Qt3D?

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d

I created some entities using qt3d in QML. For example, this code shows a `Scene3D` element that declares `RootEntity` which is another QML element that contains the scene graph:

```
Scene3D
{
    id : scene3d
    anchors.fill: parent
    focus: true
    aspects: ["render", "logic", "input"]
    hoverEnabled: true
    cameraAspectRatioMode: Scene3D.AutomaticAspectRatio


    antialiasing: true

    RootEntity
    {
        id:root
    }

}
```

**RootEntity.qml**:

```
Entity {
id:root

property double x : 0.0


Camera {
    id: mainCamera
    projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
    fieldOfView: 45
    aspectRatio: 16/9
    nearPlane : 0.1
    farPlane : 1000.0
    position: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 4.49373, -3.78577)
    upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
    viewCenter: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.5, 0.0)

}

OrbitCameraController
{
    id: mainCameraController
    camera: mainCamera
}

components: [
    RenderSettings {

        Viewport {
            normalizedRect: Qt.rect(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
            RenderSurfaceSelector {
                CameraSelector {
                    id: cameraSelector
                    camera: mainCamera
                    FrustumCulling {
                        ClearBuffers {
                            buffers: ClearBuffers.AllBuffers
                            clearColor: "#444449"
                            NoDraw {}
                        }
                        LayerFilter {
                            filterMode: LayerFilter.DiscardAnyMatchingLayers
                            layers: [topLayer]
                        }
                        LayerFilter {
                            filterMode: LayerFilter.AcceptAnyMatchingLayers
                            layers: [topLayer]
                            ClearBuffers {
                                buffers: ClearBuffers.DepthBuffer
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }      
    },
    InputSettings {}
]

Layer {
    id: topLayer
    recursive: true
}

ListModel {
    id: entityModel
    ListElement { x:0;y:0;z:0 }
}

NodeInstantiator
{
    id:instance

    model: entityModel

    delegate: Entity {
        id: sphereEntity
        components: [
            SphereMesh
            {
                id:sphereMesh
                radius: 0.3
            },

            PhongMaterial
            {
                id: materialSphere
                ambient:"red"
            },

            Transform {
                id: transform
                translation:Qt.vector3d(x, y, z)
            }
        ]
    }
}

MouseDevice
{
    id: mouseDev
}

MouseHandler
{
    id: mouseHandler
    sourceDevice: mouseDev

    onPressed:
    {
        x++;
        entityModel.append({"x":x,"y":0.0,"z": Math.random()})
    }
}
}
```

[image: Output screenshot]

When the mouse is clicked in my Scene3D, one sphere is displayed.

I don't know how to delete a specific Entity or create undo/redo effect by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in Qt3d.
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is too broad. _undo_  implies that you perform some transformation with your Entities but there is nothing in your question about that. Please clarify the question and provide [mcve] so we can run and test it.

Comment: You have to implement it by yourself. Please read the [Overview of Qt's Undo Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundo.html) page for more info. To delete an element from the `ListModel` you can use [ListModel.remove](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#remove-method) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to maintain a global list of `Qt.vector3d` elements and use it to record the position of the spheres that are removed with the "Undo" operation:

- When the user hits <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, create a new `Qt.vector3d` object to store the position of the last sphere rendered (that is, the one that was last appended to `entityModel`) and add that position to the global list of 3d vectors;
- Then, to remove a sphere from the screen, call `entityModel.remove()` with the index of the sphere that needs to be erased;

The "Redo" operation simply does the opposite:

- When the user hits <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, the last element of the global list of 3d vectors holds the location of the lastest sphere removed: append this position to `entityModel` so the sphere can be rendered again;
- Then, remember to erase this position from the global list so the next Undo operation can render a different sphere;

**RootEntity.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

import QtQml.Models 2.15

import Qt3D.Core 2.12
import Qt3D.Render 2.12
import Qt3D.Extras 2.12
import Qt3D.Input 2.12

Entity {
    id: root

    // global list of Qt.vector3d elements that store the location of the spheres that are removed
    property variant removedSpheres : []

    // x-coordinate of the next sphere that will be added
    property double x : 0.0

    Camera {
        id: mainCamera
        projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
        fieldOfView: 45
        aspectRatio: 16/9
        nearPlane : 0.1
        farPlane : 1000.0
        position: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 4.49373, -3.78577)
        upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
        viewCenter: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.5, 0.0)
    }

    OrbitCameraController {
        id: mainCameraController
        camera: mainCamera
    }

    components: [
        RenderSettings {

            Viewport {
                normalizedRect: Qt.rect(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                RenderSurfaceSelector {
                    CameraSelector {
                        id: cameraSelector
                        camera: mainCamera
                        FrustumCulling {
                            ClearBuffers {
                                buffers: ClearBuffers.AllBuffers
                                clearColor: "#444449"
                                NoDraw {}
                            }
                            LayerFilter {
                                filterMode: LayerFilter.DiscardAnyMatchingLayers
                                layers: [topLayer]
                            }
                            LayerFilter {
                                filterMode: LayerFilter.AcceptAnyMatchingLayers
                                layers: [topLayer]
                                ClearBuffers {
                                    buffers: ClearBuffers.DepthBuffer
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        InputSettings {}
    ]

    Layer {
        id: topLayer
        recursive: true
    }

    ListModel {
        id: entityModel

        ListElement { x: 0; y: 0; z: 0 }
    }

    NodeInstantiator {
        id: instance

        model: entityModel

        delegate: Entity {
            id: sphereEntity

            components: [
                SphereMesh { id:sphereMesh; radius: 0.3 },

                PhongMaterial { id: materialSphere; ambient:"red" },

                Transform { id: transform; translation:Qt.vector3d(x, y, z) }
            ]
        }
    }

    MouseDevice {
        id: mouseDev
    }

    MouseHandler {
        id: mouseHandler
        sourceDevice: mouseDev

        onPressed:
        {
            if (mouse.button === Qt.LeftButton)
            {
                console.log("LeftButton: new sphere")

                // add new sphere
                entityModel.append( {"x" : ++root.x, "y" : 0.0, "z" : Math.random()} )
            }

            if (mouse.button === Qt.MiddleButton)
            {
                console.log("MiddleButton: clear spheres")

                // removes all spheres (can't be undone)
                root.x = 0;
                entityModel.clear();
                removedSpheres.length = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    KeyboardDevice {
        id: keyboardDev
    }

    KeyboardHandler {
        id: keyboardHandler
        sourceDevice: keyboardDev
        focus: true

        onPressed: {
            // handle CTRL+Z: undo
            if (event.key === Qt.Key_Z && (event.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier))
            {
                console.log("CTRL+Z")

                // remove the last sphere added to the screen
                let lastIdx = entityModel.count - 1;
                if (lastIdx >= 0)
                {
                    // save sphere position before removal
                    removedSpheres.push(Qt.vector3d(entityModel.get(lastIdx).x, entityModel.get(lastIdx).y, entityModel.get(lastIdx).z));

                    // remove sphere from the model
                    entityModel.remove(lastIdx);
                }
            }

            // handle CTRL+Y: redo
            if (event.key === Qt.Key_Y && (event.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier))
            {
                console.log("CTRL+Y")

                // add the last sphere removed back into the model
                if (removedSpheres.length > 0)
                {
                    // add the sphere
                    let lastIdx = removedSpheres.length - 1;
                    entityModel.append( {"x" : removedSpheres[lastIdx].x, "y" : removedSpheres[lastIdx].y, "z" : removedSpheres[lastIdx].z} )

                    // erase the last item added to removedSpheres
                    removedSpheres.pop()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning (without an example implementation) that there's also the [Qt Undo System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundocommand.html) :) Might be an overkill but it's always good to know that it exists.

Comment: I know that there is [Qt Undo System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundocommand.html) . but this is for widgets. it needs QT += widgets and works when we works with widgets.

Comment: now I use qt3d . my base object is scene3d . Thank you all for your response .